# Java program displays wrong order of numbers in a diagonal of a multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In my Java program I want two diagonals of a multidimensional array to be displayed, but the second diagonal shows the wrong order of numbers, the inverse order of numbers to be more precise. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class arrays
{
int array[][]={{450,463,267,685},
                {467,483,236,898},
                {457,124,685,457},
                {986,357,321,786}};
int option=1, op=0, i=0;
public arrays()
{
    while(option==1){
        int num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1-Diagonal1 2-Diagonal2"));
        switch(num){
            case 1:
                diagonal1(array);
            break;
            case 2:
                diagonal2(array);
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("That's the wrong number");
                System.out.println("- - - - -");
                option=0;
        }
    }
}
public void diagonal1(int array[][]){
    for(int z=0;z<array.length;z++){
        for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
            if(x==i){
                for(int y=0;y<i;y++){
                    System.out.print("    ");
                }
                System.out.print(array[x][z]);
            }
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("- - - - -");
}
public void diagonal2(int array[][]){
    int v=3;
    for(int z=0;z<array.length;z++){
        if(v==-1){
            v=3;
        }
        for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
            if(x==v){
                for(int y=0;y<v;y++){
                    System.out.print("    ");
                }
                System.out.print(array[x][z]);
                v--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("- - - - -");
  }
 }
```

It gives me this:

```
            986
        124
    236
685
```

When it should give me this:

```
            685
        236
    124
986
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In diagonal2 method, variable z is referring to the row number and x is referring to column number.

Below is the corrected code:

```
public static void diagonal2(int array[][]){
int v=3;
for(int z=0;z<array.length;z++){
  if(v==-1){
    v=3;
  }
  for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
    if(x==v){
      for(int y=0;y<v;y++){
        System.out.print("    ");
      }
      System.out.print(array[z][x]); // This is corrected
      v--;
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("- - - - -");
```

}